# Can polypropylene be separated from polyethylene ?

Tags: organic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, experimental-chemistry

What techniques are available for sorting on a large scale?

Answer (score 3):

Practically only by mechanical means. Recycling numbers:

2 – HDPE (High-Density Polyethylene) 
4 – LDPE (Low-Density Polyethylene) 
5 – PP (Polypropylene)